# Почему SSE листинг выполняется очень медленно?

Tags: ассемблер

Есть такой листинг:

```
xor eax, eax
@@:
movups xmm0, xword[buf+eax]
pxor xmm0, xword[xmm01] ; db 16 dup(0x1)
movups xword[buf+eax], xmm0
add eax, 16
cmp eax, sizeof.buf ; 512
jb @b
```

(Суть такова: заменить в выделенной области памяти 512 байт нулями или единицами. Если нули — заменить единицами, если единицы — нулями)

И есть такой аналог:

```
xor     ecx, ecx
@@:     xor     byte[buf+ecx], 0x1
inc     ecx
cmp     ecx, sizeof.buf
jne     @b
```

Запускаю на своём старом ноутбуке на Intel Pentium 4 и получаю такие результаты:

Первый листинг: 3 601, 3 357, 3 249, 3 243, 3 334 ns
Второй листинг: 3 218, 3 192, 3 564, 3 238, 3 595 ns

В чём проблема? Почему SSE так прошляпился?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movups` **на старых** процессорах выполняется значительно медленнее `movaps` (с выровненным адресом) (но вряд ли в 10 раз)

`xword[xmm01]` стоит записать в регистр и использовать его. Иначе получается доступ к двум разным участкам памяти на каждом обороте цикла

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я извиняюсь - ошибся в расчётах, и сейчас редактирую ответ - SSE медленнее, чем второй листинг на 100-200 нс: 3 218 VS 3 601, 3 192 VS 3357, 3564 VS 3249.   UPD: Если загнать xmm01 в регистр, то SSE уже обгоняет второй листинг на 100-150 нс.

Answer (score 0):

В современным процессорах ширина шины между процессором и кеш-памятью достигает 16-32 байт, что и позволяет добиться роста скорости при применении SSE для пересылки данных, но в твоем случае ширина шины всего 8 байт, что аннулирует все преимущества SSE при пересылки данных.